# Copy and paste passwords in windows server 2003 login screen?

Tags: windows-server-2003, remote-desktop

The password for our windows server 2003 account is very long and complex, so I don't want to enter it each time by hand when I log in via RDP. However, copy/paste in the login screen seems to be disabled, so I have to. Can this be triggered by some policy? Or is there another way to enable this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by writing a small [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com)-Script that types the clipboard buffer after some seconds.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a RDP shortcut and keep the password saved in this- I would not advise that this is a good idea because of the security implications.

Answer (score 2):

You can not do this.  Sorry if this wasn't the answer you wanted.  You don't want your password in your pastebuffer anyways.  Huge security risk.

Comment: which is not as bad as on screen

Answer (score 1):

I use [1Password](https://agilebits.com/onepassword) to solve this problem. It has an Auto-Type feature that avoids using the copy/paste buffer and types it into the password field. It's been many years since I switched over from [KeePass](http://keepass.info/) but I'm pretty sure I used it to solve the same RDP problem. It has the advantage of being free but I much prefer 1Password.